# Reading a NFC Mifare card raw data in android

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, acr122

I'm trying to read the content of a Mifare Ultralight card using the NFC contactless reader ACR122U Android SDK.

I am able to get following hex values

```
01 03 A0 0C 44 03 15 D1 01 11 54 02 65 6E 33 34
```

But I am unable to get my actual data. Please guide me how to extract byte array from above hex values.

Comment: Just check this link you can achieve that http://www.coderanch.com/t/450379/java/java/Hex-String-byte-array

Answer (score 6):

So it seems that you read 4 pages starting at page 4 from this MIFARE Ultralight tag. Moreover, the tag seems to be formatted according to the NFC Forum Type 2 Tag Operation specification (available from the [NFC Forum website](http://www.nfc-forum.org/)).

A Type 2 Tag contains a series of tag-length-value (TLV) structures:

```
01 (Tag: Lock Control TLV)
  03 (Length: 3 bytes)
  A0 0C 44 (Value: Information on position and function of lock bytes)
03 (Tag: NDEF Message TLV)
  15 (Length: 21 bytes)
  D101115402656E3334... (Value: NDEF message)
```

You would have to issue a read command for the next 4 pages to obtain the remaining data of the NDEF message.

For now, we know, that the tag contains an NDEF message starting with

```
D101115402656E3334
```

This translates to

```
D1 (Header byte of record 1)
    - Message begin is set (= first record of an NDEF message)
    - Message end is set (= last record of an NDEF message)
    - Short record flag is set (= Payload length field consists of 1 byte only)
    - Type Name Format = 0x1 (= Type field contains an NFC Forum well-known type)
  01 (Type length: 1 byte)
  11 (Payload length: 17 bytes)
  54 (Type: "T")
  02656E3334... (Payload field)
```

The payload field of an NFC Forum Text record decodes like this:

```
02 (Status byte: Text is UTF-8 encoded, Language code has a length of 2 bytes)
656E (Language code: "en")
3334... (Text: "34"...)
```